# jQuery: Insert markup before $(this)

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to use `.insertBefore()` to insert some markup before a specific element. However `insertBefore()` takes a class name as a string. Is it possible to do something like .insertBefore($(this)) ?

Comment: `.insertBefore()` takes any valid jQuery selector, not just a class name as a string. Please post a complete code example.

Comment: And it will also take a valid jQuery Object (From [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) : `$("h2").insertBefore($(".container"));`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can take any ID Selector or Class 
For example

1. ID Selection

   $( "li" ).insertBefore( "#Insert" );
   $( "li" ).insertBefore( "$(this)" );

   2. Class Selection

   $( "li" ).insertBefore( ".Insert" );

Answer (score -1):

Yes, insertBefore can take a selector, or an element among others...

http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/